# mysqli insert statement error

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, insert

Just updating my mysql connections and so forth to use this mysqli implementation.
I'm trying to run the code below...

The connection to the database is fine and works, and when I substitute the ? for real values it works. Can someone help me with the error below?

Thanks.

The code:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO customers (cap_login, cap_pword, title, firstname, lastname, email)
VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
echo $sql;

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($username, $pass_hash, $title, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

The error:

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in....
```

I echoed out the sql statment and got this:

```
INSERT INTO customers (cap_login, cap_pword, title, firstname, lastname, email) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Comment: specified the type first, then pass the variables i.e `$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$username, $pass_hash, $title, $firstname, $lastname, $email);`   See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax of mysqli_stmt:

```
mysqli_stmt::bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
```

You missed to specified the types of the variable

Try

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssssss",$username, $pass_hash, $title, $firstname, $lastname, $email);
```

Comment: Oh.. yes in PDO we initialize a PDO object. Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 1):

Before using a function one have to read [the manual page for the right syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php), which is

```
bind_param ( string $types , mixed &$var1 [, mixed &$... ] )
                    ^^^^^^
```

So, first parameter have to be a string like `'sssssss'`